# symfony 4.3 on OVH server, cache clear return error 255 (while composer update / heroku deploy from github)

Tags: symfony, heroku, ssh, symfony4, symfony-4.3

I did a symfony 4.3 app, and would like to put it on my OVH server. I Saved my app on github, and ignored .env file, plus all files and folders already ignored in .gitignore. Then, in SSH, in my OVH server, I did a git clone to get my app on it. Then I did a composer update to get all the files and folders missing (var, vendor, .env). This gave me the error :

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
[KO]
script cache:clear returned with error 255
!!
script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

And vendor was present on my server, but neither var nor .env. So I manually transfered .env in FTP via filezilla, I changed it with APP_ENV=prod, then I created manually (still with filezilla) a var folder, with cache and log folders in it (I didn't transfered mine so that it's empty, so already cleared). Then I checked : my website was working on the internet (from my server, not in local).

So, problem solved ? ... Yes and no. The website works, but my purpose isn't to post a website on the internet, but to learn (I follow a symfony lesson on udemy). I got to learn how to make automatically deployments with heroku.

So I create a heroku account, linked it to my github account, and to my app. But when I try to deploy manually from heroku (to check it works before doing automatically deployments), I still have a cache clear 255 error (the [modified : some numbers and letters] are things I hidden in the error message because I wondered if this could be sensitive) :

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
        [KO]
       Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
       !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "/tmp/build_[modified : some numbers and letters]/.env" environment file. in /tmp/build_[modified : some numbers and letters]/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:484
       !!  Stack trace:
       !!  #0 /tmp/build_[modified : some numbers and letters]/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(65): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad(false, Array)
       !!  #1 /tmp/build_[modified : some numbers and letters]/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(85): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load('/tmp/build_a7cc...')
       !!  #2 /tmp/build_[modified : some numbers and letters]/config/bootstrap.php(15): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->loadEnv('/tmp/build_a7cc...')
       !!  #3 /tmp/build_[modified : some numbers and letters]/bin/console(30): require('/tmp/build_a7cc...')
       !!  #4 {main}
       !!    thrown in /tmp/build_[modified : some numbers and letters]/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 484
       !!  
       Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
 !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
 !     
 !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
 !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
 !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
 !     in your 'composer.json'.
 !     
 !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
 !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
 !     
 !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
 !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
 !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
 !     
 !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
 !     Push failed
```

Because of the error message, I looked in my composer.json file, I have this :

```
"scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
```

Is there something wrong with it ? I don't see what I could change in it.

I tried many things I found on the internet :

https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/406
composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts.
composer install

executed in ssh didn't create any errors in itself, but didn't resolved the problem when trying again to deploy on heroku

I also try what the teacher in my lesson proposed in this case :

```
composer config disable-tls true
composer install
```

Same : no errors when doing this, but didn't solve the problem when trying to deploy on heroku

And many things since yesterday, I don't remember everything I tried :-/ but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the environment variable SYMFONY_ENV = prod in Heroku and the APP_ENV = prod in your .env file.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! I didn't know about the SYMFONY_ENV var. But I did it, I created it in heroku > settings > config vars, and the problem is unfortunatly still the same

Comment: And what about your .env file?? Make sure you set APP_ENV=prod in .env file

Comment: Sorry, I already told I've put "APP_ENV = prod" in the first message, so I forgot to tell it in my response, but I should have. So already done ! I checked it with command ligne "nano" in ssh.

Comment: @fred make sure your .env file is committed to your repository, also add symfony/dotenv as a composer dependency for Symfony to actually use the environment variables defined in the .env file.